# OS X program to discover application menu items and generate accelerators / hotkeys for them?

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Would it be possible to write an objective- C program be written that uses os x system api's to find the menu items in an application and then adds application specific shortcuts for each of them?

The following Apple knowledge base article describes how to manually create shortcuts. That is more work than I want to do for e.g Intellij with 280 menu entries.  However, it does provide important evidence that OS X does have the underlying ability to map key combinations to menu items. So it is a matter of discovering the c-api's involved.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3957

Motivation:  For a keyboardist that seeks the ability to access all menu items from keyboard it is well known that in at least that area OS X is more difficult to use than some other operating systems e.g. Linux and Windows (in which accelerator keys are better supported).

Yes there are typically built-in shortcuts for the most commonly used items - but what if the "commonly used items" do not precisely overlap the menu items I use?

Let us take example of a rich editor: Intellij Idea. There are over 250 menu items.  How would I possibly memorize so many hotkeys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround that I have come to is:

1. IJ allows mnemonics via the Option key.
2. Other programs allow most menu items to be reached by typing the first characters of the
   menu items.

These are not at all completely satisfying, but are the best I could find after months of poking at it.